# Why javascript class and function has constructor property that equals 'Function'?

Tags: javascript

Say there're js function `func` and class `cls`:

```
function func() {}
class cls() {}
```

I totally understand:

```
func === func.prototype.constructor // true
cls === cls.prototype.constructor   // true
```

but can't understand:

```
func.constructor === Function // true
cls.constructor === Function  // true
```

Why both things have `constructor` property though they are constructors themselves?

Comment: `class cls() {}` is just a new syntax, it falls back to `function cls() {}`

Comment: "Why both things have constructor property though they are constructors themselves?" — Why would they not?!

Comment: `func` is a function, so its constructor is `Function`.

Comment: More generally, constructors are functions.

Comment: `typeof func.constructor` will return `function` and `typeof new Function` will also return `function` that is why `func.constructor === Function` is valid, `Why both things have constructor property though they are constructors themselves?`
it's the default empty constructor that you don't define when you're defining your object declaration.

Comment: @ZohirSalak cheers mate now I understand, the constructor property aforementioned is inherited from 'Function.prototype' object

Comment: Yes, as you know Javascript is all functions and callbacks